# IIS : Exception from HRESULT: 0xC00CEF03

Tags: windows, iis

I have my website hosted on IIS with window 2016 OS. When I am going to disable the Form Authentication under IIS, it is giving me the following error.

Form Authentication.

Exception from HRESULT: 0xC00CEF03

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why you need to disable `Form Authentication.`?

Comment: It is asking me the credentials when i access the website. Hence, need to disable.

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar issue but it occurred when i was trying to disable the 'Machine key' - 'automatically generate at runtime' and then Applying the same.

For your error, please verify if the authentication is enabled/disabled for Default Web-site. Change that setting and then try disabling you specific websites status. It should ideally work.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this error stem from three different controls on the authentication method:

- If configuring the authentication method on an application, and the authentication method you're trying to disable is *enabled* on the containing site.
- If configuring the authentication method on a site, and the authentication method you're trying to disable is *enabled* on the Default Web Site.
- If configuring the authentication method that has been defined in a `web.config` file. You should adjust it in the config file.

Answer (score 0):

0xC00CEF03 error code translates to WR_E_NSPREFIXWITHEMPTYNSURI which refers to “Writer: cannot use prefix with empty namespace URI” ([Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms753129(v=vs.85))).

This error occurs when there is something wrong with the web.config file. It’s probably corrupted or there are incompatible tags and parameters. As a result of this corruption and incompatibility, IIS is not able to read this file. Therefore, it can’t make a change.

The issue mostly happens after migration because a piece of configuration that works in the older version of IIS (and .NET Framework) probably became unsupported in the newer version.

The shortest way of finding what part of the web.config is causing the issue is to remove sections one by one and test. High-level steps:

1. Remove a section from the bottom of the file (Let’s say you removed `system.serviceModel` section)
2. If the issue goes away, add the section back and start removing the subsections of it one by one. (For example, `ws2007HttpBinding` subsection in `system.serviceModel` section)
3. If the issue goes away again, bring the subsection back and go through each lines. Prefixes like `wsid:`, `asm:`, and `trust:` are the most common causes of this issue

Source: [0xC00CEF03 error (Cannot use prefix with empty namespace URI)](https://port135.com/0xc00cef03-empty-namespace-uri/)